# Node.js Spawn Child Process w/ Colors (native)

Tags: node.js, subprocess

A note to duplicate question hawks: I've looked at related questions, and most seem to relate to using `mocha`, but this is about native use of `spawn` and piping IO streams between parent and child processes.

I'm responsible for maintaining a Node.js CLI tool for facilitating our QA teams, and I've accidentally caused the loss of colors when running Cucumber tests. This problem appears unrelated to Cucumber, as I can reproduce the issue without invoking the Cucumber runtime and only using Node-native code.

I'm using a TTY shell, as are most of my users (though some might not), and here is the simplest example of the problem:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

spawn('node', [ '-p', '-e', 'process.stdout.isTTY' ], { stdio: [ 'ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit' ] });

const subprocess = spawn('node', [ '-p', '-e', 'process.stdout.isTTY' ], { stdio: 'pipe' });
subprocess.stdout.pipe(process.stdout, { end: false });
subprocess.stderr.pipe(process.stderr, { end: false });
```

The first spawned subprocess should return `true` with syntax highlighting in a TTY shell, but the second example returns `undefined` without syntax highlighting. I understand that the `options.stdio` implementation differs, but I've written a more robust wrapper to `spawn` so that event handlers can be added at a later date for supporting more complex actions, or as I needed for further diagnostic reasons when adding some features. As such, I'm trying to understand what is different between piping to `process.stdout` and using `options.stdio = [ 'ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit' ]` or `options.stdio = [ 'ignore', 1, 2 ]`.

Comment: Just to make sure: do you know [`colors` was intentionally broken recently](https://snyk.io/blog/open-source-npm-packages-colors-faker/) and have you already made sure that's not your problem?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for the info, but no. This isn't related to `colors`, but yes we had a minor meltdown in our CI/CD solution because many build agents were stuck in the infinite loop from that particular event.

This specific issue is exhibited through the native use of Node.js properties, which was why I wanted to call that out explicitly in the title/question.